# Store key values as indexes of array in php

Tags: php

Theres an array in php like following

```
Array
(

 [0] => Array
    (
        [int_city_id] => 1
        [txt_cityname] => Lucknow
        [time_stamp] => 2017-09-18 14:11:05
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
        [int_city_id] => 3
        [txt_cityname] => Kanpur
        [time_stamp] => 2017-09-14 12:09:46
    )


   )
```

Need to save it like following

```
  Array
(
        [1] => Lucknow
       ,
        [3] => Kanpur
   )
```

How can I achieve this in php using the best way

I tried:

```
   foreach ($cities as $key => $value) {
     # code...
     $newarr[$value['int_city_id']]=$value['txt_cityname'];
   }
   print_r($newarr);
```

Comment: go over your array and create a dictionary?

Comment: Before you ask for the “best way”, come up with _any_ way yourself - especially for something this trivial.

Comment: @CBroe Please check edit

Comment: @Akhil Sahu: Your try seems to do the trick, doesn't it? 'the best way' is not a very good question, it asks for opinion-based answers. If you don't like your code, then indicate what you want improved.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes it does Need a direct method to do this in php inbuilt type

Comment: No, you don’t need a direct, built-in method - there isn’t one, because this is to specific. Make a function out of what you have, that should be good enough. You can of course get “fancier”, and replace the foreach loop with one of the functions that run over all array elements and do something with it ... but that won’t improve much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use build-in functions like this:

```
$newArray = array_combine(array_column($cities,'int_city_id'),
                          array_column($cities,'txt_cityname'));
```

However, why would you? Since you already have a `foreach` loop in which you do other stuff with the `$cities` array, why not build the new array in that? In other words there's nothing wrong with:

```
foreach ($cities as $index => $city) {
  # code...
  $newArray[$city['int_city_id']] = $city['txt_cityname'];
}
```

If you use the values of `$city` a lot, you can extract them first:

```
foreach ($cities as $index => $city) {
  extract($city,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,'city');
  # code...
  $newArray[$city_int_city_id] = $city_txt_cityname;
}
```

It looks a bit cleaner and would execute the line that builds the new array slightly faster, but only by a tiny margin. Of course the `extract()` also takes time, so only do this if you use the values of `$city` repeatedly.